# How do I edit this code to not append particular symbols, conditionally to avoid multiple operators in a succession?

Tags: javascript

I am making an expression calculator. This code has buttons for numerals and mathematical operators. on every click the value of button is getting appended to the paragraph tag.

**Requirements:**

1. Every time I press a button with numerical value it should be appended to the paragraph.
2. Every time I press a operator it should be appended only the first time and not again. Eg - I don't want my calculator to accept '5 + + * 2' only simple expressions like '5 + 2 - 3 * 4' should be accepted.
   How do i change this code to accept a operator only once even if I click on it multiple times?.

Please run the snippet once to understand what I am saying. Thanks.

```js
function append(a){
var z = document.getElementById(a).value;
  if (document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML == '0')
    document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = document.getElementById(a).value;
    else
    document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML += document.getElementById(a).value;

};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<title>JS Calculator</title>
<head>
<body>
<div>
<p id='text1' style="border-style: inset;width:200px;display:inline-block;">0</p><br>
<button value="1" id='a1' onclick="append(this.id)">1</button>
<button value="2" id='a2' onclick="append(this.id)">2</button>
<button value="3" id='a3' onclick="append(this.id)">3</button>
<button value="4" id='a4' onclick="append(this.id)">4</button>
<button value="5" id='a5' onclick="append(this.id)">5</button>
<button value="6" id='a6' onclick="append(this.id)">6</button>
<button value="7" id='a7' onclick="append(this.id)">7</button>
<button value="8" id='a8' onclick="append(this.id)">8</button>
<button value="9" id='a9' onclick="append(this.id)">9</button>
<button value="0" id='a0' onclick="append(this.id)">0</button>
<br>
<button value=" + " id='ap' onclick="append(this.id)">+</button>
<button value=" - " id='am' onclick="append(this.id)">-</button>
<button value=" * " id='amm' onclick="append(this.id)">*</button>
<button value=" / " id='ad' onclick="append(this.id)">/</button>
<button value=" = " id='ae' onclick="">=</button>

</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isNaN(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if the button clicked is a number and see if the last character in your text - `slice(-1)` is a number or not

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text1');

function append(a) {
  var z = document.getElementById(a).value;
  if (isNaN(z) && isNaN(text.innerHTML.trim().slice(-1)))
    return;
  text.innerHTML += z;
};
```

```html
<div>
  <p id='text1' style="border-style: inset;width:200px;display:inline-block;">0</p><br>
  <button value="1" id='a1' onclick="append(this.id)">1</button>
  <button value="2" id='a2' onclick="append(this.id)">2</button>
  <button value="3" id='a3' onclick="append(this.id)">3</button>
  <button value="4" id='a4' onclick="append(this.id)">4</button>
  <button value="5" id='a5' onclick="append(this.id)">5</button>
  <button value="6" id='a6' onclick="append(this.id)">6</button>
  <button value="7" id='a7' onclick="append(this.id)">7</button>
  <button value="8" id='a8' onclick="append(this.id)">8</button>
  <button value="9" id='a9' onclick="append(this.id)">9</button>
  <button value="0" id='a0' onclick="append(this.id)">0</button>
  <br>
  <button value=" + " id='ap' onclick="append(this.id)">+</button>
  <button value=" - " id='am' onclick="append(this.id)">-</button>
  <button value=" * " id='amm' onclick="append(this.id)">*</button>
  <button value=" / " id='ad' onclick="append(this.id)">/</button>
  <button value=" = " id='ae' onclick="">=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: did not work when I replaced your exact js code in my file, I had to make  'text' local to the function to make it work. any idea why?

Comment: @muditPanwar Are you sure that it was in the correct scope ?